# Angular 7.1.1 PWA ServiceWorker on Edge doesn't load

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I have reproduced the Angular PWA project documented at: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started , when I test in Chrome, it works flawlessly, when I run it in Microsoft Edge, it looks like the ServiceWorker is not loaded. Has anyone experienced the same issue? My goal is to create a PWA application using Angular that will run in Chrome but also in Microsoft Edge.

Here's my config:

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.0
Node: 10.14.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.0
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.0
@angular/cli                      7.1.0
@angular/pwa                      0.11.0
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.0
@schematics/angular               7.1.0
@schematics/update                0.11.0
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1
```

**Edge**
[image]

---

**Chrome**
[image]

Comment: Check your Edge version first: https://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers

Comment: My edge version is: Microsoft Edge 40.15063.674.0, EdgeHTML 15.15063

Comment: That is why, 15 is red in that chart.

Comment: @wannadream if I understand correctly the caniuse.com website, in my version I need to enable it...

Comment: yes, you need to enable it manually.

Comment: @wannadream Thanks for pointing it out. I will check with my IT team why the software was not updated to the latest version.

Comment: @wannadream I validated with my home setup of Edge on version EdgeHTML 17.17134 and it does work now. I see the service workers in the Edge debugger. Thanks. I did enable it on the office computer with EdgeHTML 15.15063 but it was not showing... . I will close the issue as this solves my quesiton. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @wannadream pointed out, Service Workers are not supported on all version of Edge. caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers. On my office computer at version EdgeHTML 15.15063, it was not working eventhough I enabled the service workers flag. Using the home computer with Edge version EdgeHTML 17.17134 it works no problem with the Service Workers showing under the Edge Debugger.